# I cannot run texnic centre on my miktex

Tags: macros

When I try to run `latex.exe` on my document, the following shows up:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.90\miktex\bin\latex.exe
Cannot execute the command. Error:The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you run `latex.exe`? In a command shell? Or is it a subprocess from a TeX editor? Where is your document located? We need more informations.

Comment: It certainly should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\latex.exe`,  not `…\MiKTeX2.90\…`. Another  question: did you install MiKTeX 2.9 prior to TeXnicCenter?

Answer (score 1):

Step1 : you must have installed miktex first

Step2 : When you install texnic center in windows 7/8 all configuration will be  set

Step3 : otherwise manually you can set the path by going into Build ->> define output profiles and set the correct compiler.

[image: defineoutputprofile]